# where can I get the intraday data for S&P 500

Tags: finance

I am trying to analysis the price of S&P 500 during the flash crash in 2010. Where can I get the data?

Comment: This question is frequently asked. See for example http://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/18215/where-to-get-long-time-historical-intraday-data/18219#18219

Comment: Hi, NANA Please Check http://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/141/what-data-sources-are-available-online