# Where to retrieve financial data?

Tags: equities, historical-data, fundamentals, european

I am struggeling finding an updated list of free sources for historical financial data. My main interest is for intraday european stock markets data and companies' fundamentals data, but it would be also nice to have other markets. Alternatively even data for U.S.A. would be appreciated. If available, also real time sources would be great. Thanks and best regards.

Comment: This thread is very helpful for US intraday data: [Where to get long time historical intrady data](https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/18215/where-to-get-long-time-historical-intraday-data)

Comment: Thanks for the references. Actually those responses are quite back in time and mostly focused on US markets (e. g. I can see Yahoo that if I am not wrong does not provide APIs anymore). Do you think it would be possible to have an update on sources with a focus on European markets? As per your knowledge, are there good free sources or should I start giving up on not paying fees?