# Source for Intraday or High-frequency stock price data

Tags: equities, returns, market-data, high-frequency, intraday

I am in search for intraday (some observations per day would be fine) or high-frequency data for stock prices. I have for example 3.000 ISIN numbers of German companies and want to get the intraday/high-frequency stock price data over the last 10 years.
Does anyone have an idea, where I could get these data?
Many thanks.

Comment: This is asked relatively frequently - albeit not for Germany specific. You can check the sources [here](https://quant.stackexchange.com/q/18215/54838). As much as I know, that will not be available for free (and you will need a system that can handle that much data).

Comment: I know that Deutsche Börse and Xetra have publicly available datasets with 1min bars available here https://registry.opendata.aws/deutsche-boerse-pds/